# A variable with two columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates, series

I am not sure how my variable, df['education'], when printed out has two identical columns, rather than just being one. When I check the type of the variable it says it is a Series, but how can a series have two columns?

```
 df2['education']

                education            education
0        Higher education     Higher education
1        Higher education     Higher education
2        Higher education     Higher education
3        Higher education     Higher education
4        Higher education     Higher education
5        Higher education     Higher education
6        Higher education     Higher education
7        Higher education     Higher education

[4743 rows x 2 columns]
```

How can I merge the two or keep just one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem duplicated columns names, so if select get all columns in `DataFrame`.

Solution is upgrade pandas for [0.19.0+](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#read-csv-has-improved-support-for-duplicate-column-names) if use `read_csv`, which by default avoid it, it create 2 columns `education` and `education.1`.

Another solution is use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for add count number to duplicated columns names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abc'),
                    'B':[4,5,4],
                    'C':[7,8,9]})
df.columns = ['id', 'education', 'education']
print (df)
  id  education  education
0  a          4          7
1  b          5          8
2  c          4          9

s = df.columns.to_series()
count = s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str)

df.columns = s.mask(count != '0', s + '.' + count)
print (df)
  id  education  education.1
0  a          4            7
1  b          5            8
2  c          4            9
```